# Removal of double quotes and substitution of comma inside it

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed

I'm looking for a command which can remove one/two double quotes from a CSV format file and comma's inside them to be substituted with space so that the whole field can look like one.

Ex: `""Wembley,London""` to be shown as `Wembley London` under one column in the csv.

Also, the command for "Wembley,London" as Wembley London. Irrespective of the field position the script would be reading the file.

I tried the below commands but its not useful.

```
sed 's/\"//g' $fname >  $Target/sample_UPS1.csv
sed 's/\,/ /g' $Target/sample_UPS1.csv >  $Target/sample_UPS1.csv

awk -F'""' -v OFS='' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(",", " ", $i) } 1' $fname | sed 's/\"//g'   > $Target/sample_UPS.txt ##For removal of two double quotes and substitution of comma with a space##

awk -F'"' -v OFS='' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(",", " ", $i) } 1' $Target/sample_UPS.txt | sed 's/\"//g' > $Target/sample_UPS1.txt ##For removal of double quotes and substitution of comma with a space##
```

Both the cases, sample_ups1 being my output file.

Comment: a,b,c,1234,23,"Wembley,London",267,agty being csv fields, I need the output as a,b,c,1234,23,Wembley London,267,agty. Similarly, if one of the fields has two double quotes, the output should be as above

Comment: can you edit the question and add the same you mentioned in comment.

Comment: Related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48672/remove-comma-between-the-quotes-only-in-a-comma-delimited-file

Comment: Try, `awk -F'"' -v OFS='' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(",", " ", $i) } 1' file`

Comment: @SivaPrasath: wouldn't work with the double double quotes. Remove those first: `awk -F'"' -v OFS='' '{gsub (/""/, "\""); for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(",", " ", $i) } 1' file`

Comment: I already tried the above command. But then, what about two double quoted field?

Comment: @Abhishek i got the output as `a,b,c,1234,23,Wembley London,267,agty` for the code `awk -F'"' -v OFS='' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(",", " ", $i) } 1' file`

Comment: Yes, Siva. But what about when we have two instances of double quotes? Like below
a,b,c,1234,23,""Wembley,London"",267,agty

Answer (score 0):

If you have valid CSV, a proper CSV parser should be used. ruby's is easy to use:
if

```
cat file.csv
```

```
"""Wembley,London""",a,"b","c, ""d e"", ""f,g"",h"
```

then

```
ruby -e '
    require "csv"
    data = CSV.read ARGV.shift
    data.each {|row| 
        row.each {|field| field.delete! "\""; field.tr! ",", " "}
        puts CSV.generate_line row
    }
' file.csv
```

```
Wembley London,a,b,c  d e  f g h
```

Note that embedded quotes in a CSV field [require the quotes to be doubled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#RFC_4180_standard). If you have

```
""Wembley,London"","other stuff",...
```

then you have malformed CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Perl's [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) module can handle malformed CSV of this type:

> If there is really bad CSV data, like
>
> `1,"foo "bar" baz",42`
>
> or
>
> `1,""foo bar baz"",42`
>
> there is a way to get this data-line parsed and
>   leave the quotes inside the quoted field as-is. This can be achieved
>   by setting `allow_loose_quotes` AND making sure that the `escape_char` is
>   not equal to `quote_char`

So, for example

```
echo 'a,b,c,1234,23,""Wembley,London"",267,agty' | 
  perl -MText::CSV -lne '
    BEGIN{$p = Text::CSV->new( {allow_loose_quotes => 1, escape_char => "\\"} )} 
    print join ",", map { s/,/ /g; s/"//g; $_ } $p->fields() if $p->parse($_)
'
a,b,c,1234,23,Wembley London,267,agty
```