# Replace a character only between the double-quotes with sed or awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, csv

I have such a scenario inside a CSV file:

```
ID,PRICE,QUANTITY,ARRIVAL
01299,"41,5",1,0
26528,"412,03",0,0
38080,"2,35",0,0
38081,"2,35",0,0
..
..
```

The question I ask myself is: How do I replace `,` with the `.`, but only in the prices, enclosed within the double quotes `"..."`, in the `PRICE` column?

I tried with

```
sed -i 's/\(,\)[^ ]*\( .*\)/\1"."\2/'
```

but without success, can you give me a tip?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using the "-E" option for sed, for extended regular expression.
If you only have numbers between the quotes you could do something like this:

```
~ $ cat foo
lorem, ipsum
"5,25", foobar
"foo,bar", foobar
~ $ cat foo | sed -E 's/"([0-9]+)\,([0-9]+)"/"\1.\2"/g'
lorem, ipsum
"5.25", foobar
"foo,bar", foobar
```

If you have upper- and lowercase letters in the quotes you can extend the regexp like this:

```
~ $ cat foo | sed -E 's/"([0-9]+|[a-z]+|[A-Z]+)\,([0-9]+|[a-z]+|[A-Z]+)"/"\1.\2"/g'
lorem, ipsum
"5.25", foobar
"foo.bar", foobar
```

You can easily test your regular expressions at regex101.com:
See also: https://regex101.com/r/mlfSMp/1

Answer (score 2):

Using `csvformat` from [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```bsh
$ csvformat -D ';' file | tr , . | csvformat -d ';'
ID,PRICE,QUANTITY,ARRIVAL
01299,41.5,1,0
26528,412.03,0,0
38080,2.35,0,0
38081,2.35,0,0
```

The above command changes the CSV delimiter from the default comma to semi-colon.  It then changes all remaining commas into dots before changing the field delimiter back to comma.

Alternatively, convert the CSV to JSON using `csvjson` and modify the data with `jq`:

```bsh
$ csvjson -I file | jq -r '(.[0] | keys_unsorted | @csv), (map(.PRICE |= sub(",";".") | [.[]] | @csv)[])'
"ID","PRICE","QUANTITY","ARRIVAL"
"01299","41.5","1","0"
"26528","412.03","0","0"
"38080","2.35","0","0"
"38081","2.35","0","0"
```

Pass this through `csvformat` (with no arguments) if you want to remove any unneeded quotes.

The `jq` expression first outputs the header by taking the keys from the first object in the input array.  It then modifies the `PRICE` field of each element (changes the comma into a dot) and formats the values as CSV for output.

The difference in effect between this second variation and the first is that we only ever affect the `PRICE` column. Any embedded commas in any other field will be untouched.

---

For reference, the JSON document that `jq` gets as input from `csvjson`, given the CSV data in the question, would be

```json
[
  {"ID":"01299","PRICE":"41,5","QUANTITY":"1","ARRIVAL":"0"},
  {"ID":"26528","PRICE":"412,03","QUANTITY":"0","ARRIVAL":"0"},
  {"ID":"38080","PRICE":"2,35","QUANTITY":"0","ARRIVAL":"0"},
  {"ID":"38081","PRICE":"2,35","QUANTITY":"0","ARRIVAL":"0"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Tweaking this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48675/97255) to [Remove comma between the quotes only in a comma delimited file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/48672/97255) for an `awk` solution:

```
awk -F'"' -v OFS='"' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(",", ".", $i) } 1' infile
```

where `infile` is

```
ID,PRICE,QUANTITY,ARRIVAL
01299,"41,5",1,0
26528,"412,03",0,0
38080,"2,35",0,0
38081,"2,35",0,0
```

and the result is

```
ID,PRICE,QUANTITY,ARRIVAL
01299,"41.5",1,0
26528,"412.03",0,0
38080,"2.35",0,0
38081,"2.35",0,0
```

The explanation of the code is the same as the referenced answer so I won't repeat it, except that:

- The output field separator is now `"` (i.e. `OFS='"'`), instead of nothing (i.e. `OFS=''`), and;
- The `gsub` now swaps the comma (`","`) for a period (`"."`), instead of nothing (`""`)